# Resultado de soma de 2 campos

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou precisando una ajudinha em uma consulta. Tenho uma tabela de vendas onde tem o campo vltotal e vldevolucao, o total destes campos ja consegui, porém não estou conseguindo o resultado da soma deles. Meu script é:

```
select distinct codusur, sum(vltotal) as valor, sum(vldevolucao) as 
Devolucao, count(codcli), sum(vltotal - vldevolucao) as liquido

from pcnfsaid
where dtsaida between trunc(sysdate, 'month') and sysdate

and vlbonific = 0

and codsupervisor = 2

group by codusur

order by codusur
```

Tenho esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei se entendi mas tente "rollup" ou "cube" https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets

Comment: Preciso que o LIQUIDO seja VALOR - DEVOLUCAO. Veja nesse exemplo:
codusur 4 - 13990,36 - 419,19 o correto seria  LIQUIDO 13574,17
codusu 7 - 18832,30 - 953,80 o correto seria LIQUIDO 17878,50

Comment: Tente tirar o "distinct"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
select distinct codusur, sum(vltotal) as valor, sum(vldevolucao) as 
Devolucao, count(codcli), sum(vltotal) - sum(vldevolucao) as liquido
from pcnfsaid
where dtsaida between trunc(sysdate, 'month') and sysdate
and vlbonific = 0
and codsupervisor = 2
group by codusur
order by codusur
```

Comment: Blz! funcionou certinho! obrigado